# analytics call as last after page load.(AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do i make sure that analytics call goes as a last item after page load in Single page application?

I tried using `$viewContentLoaded` but it gets triggers before the page fetches services and load data.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded',  function () {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ui-router`, then this might work:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
   //if condition if you want to reduce the number of calls or restrict to only some state changes
   //Analytics call
      });
```